# Error while using pghistory.BeforeDelete() of django-pghistory

Tags: django

I am using [**django-pghistory  1.2.0**](https://pypi.org/project/django-pghistory/) to keep my changes using postgres triggers. For insert or update, it saves data to event table for both ORM and raw  queries. But while using delete, it throws errors.

My model:

```
@pghistory.track(
    pghistory.AfterInsert('after_insert'),
    pghistory.AfterUpdate('after_update'),
    pghistory.BeforeDelete('before_delete')
)
class TestModel(models.Model):
    int_field = models.IntegerField()
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Error:

```
    psycopg2.errors.ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: record "new" is not assigned yet
    DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                    ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_obj_id", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', NEW."id", _pgh_attach_context())"
    PL/pgSQL function pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49() line 14 at SQL statement
django.db.utils.OperationalError: record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_obj_id", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', NEW."id", _pgh_attach_context())"
PL/pgSQL function pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49() line 14 at SQL statement
```

Test API for CRUD operation:

```
class TestModelAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = TestModel.objects.create(int_field=1, char_field='c1')

        obj.int_field = 2
        obj.char_field = 'c2'
        obj.save()

        obj.delete()

        return JsonResponse(
            data={'message': 'success'},
            status=200,
        )
```

My INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .............,
    'pgtrigger',
    'pgconnection',
    'pghistory',
]
```

My database settings:

```
DATABASES = pgconnection.configure({
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "<some-value>",
        "USER": "<some-value>",
        "PASSWORD": "<some-value>",
        "HOST": "<some-value>",
        "PORT": "<some-value>",
    },
    
})
```

**Details error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgconnection/core.py", line 85, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, args)
psycopg2.errors.ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_obj_id", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', NEW."id", _pgh_attach_context())"
PL/pgSQL function pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49() line 14 at SQL statement


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/loan_mngmt_app/api/client_data_api.py", line 88, in post
    obj.delete()
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 396, in delete
    count = sql.DeleteQuery(model).delete_batch([instance.pk], self.using)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 43, in delete_batch
    num_deleted += self.do_query(self.get_meta().db_table, self.where, using=using)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 23, in do_query
    cursor = self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/media/arif/74809FD62472EDA3/SourceCode/tkdc/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgconnection/core.py", line 85, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, args)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_obj_id", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', NEW."id", _pgh_attach_context())"
PL/pgSQL function pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49() line 14 at SQL statement
```

What wrong i have done to configure **pghistory.BeforeDelete()** of **django-pghistory** and what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use **obj_fk=None** to **pghistory.track()**

```
@pghistory.track(
    pghistory.AfterInsert('after_insert'),
    pghistory.AfterUpdate('after_update'),
    pghistory.BeforeDelete('before_delete'),
    obj_fk=None
)
class TestModel(models.Model):
    int_field = models.IntegerField()
    char_field = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Without **obj_fk=None**, The trigger will be created where **pgh_obj_id** column will be present and it will be populated via **NEW."id"** into trigger's insert statement which raises the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                
                BEGIN
                    
            IF (_pgtrigger_should_ignore(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_NAME) IS TRUE) THEN
                IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
                    RETURN OLD;
                ELSE
                    RETURN NEW;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        
                    
            INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_obj_id", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', NEW."id", _pgh_attach_context());
            RETURN NULL;
        
                END;
            $function$
;
```

After using **obj_fk=None**, you run make migration and migrate command which will remove **pgh_obj_id** column and **NEW."id"** from the insert statement.

New statement will be this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pgtrigger_before_delete_f0f49()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                
                BEGIN
                    
            IF (_pgtrigger_should_ignore(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_NAME) IS TRUE) THEN
                IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
                    RETURN OLD;
                ELSE
                    RETURN NEW;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        
                    
            INSERT INTO "loan_mngmt_app_testmodelevent"
                ("int_field", "char_field", "id", "pgh_created_at", "pgh_label", "pgh_context_id") VALUES (OLD."int_field", OLD."char_field", OLD."id", NOW(), 'before_delete', _pgh_attach_context());
            RETURN NULL;
        
                END;
            $function$
;
```